# Why LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() of the RecyclerView allways returns 0?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get an item position of first visible of the  RecyclerView. For LayountManager of the RecyclerView, I'm using LinearLayoutManager. To get item position of first visible of the RecyclerView I am using `LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`, but it always returns 0.

```
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private var arrayList:List<ContentWithCategory> = ArrayList()
private lateinit var viewModel: ContentsViewModel
private lateinit var adapter: ContentsAdapter
private lateinit var title:String
private var last_content_id:Int = 0
private var category_id:Int =0

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    viewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContentsViewModel::class.java)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contents, container, false)
    progressBar=view.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressLine)
    recyclerView=view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.itemAnimator= DefaultItemAnimator()
    viewModel.findContentsByID(category_id).observe(this, Observer<List<ContentWithCategory>>{
        arrayList=it
        adapter=ContentsAdapter(context!!,arrayList,this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        if(category_id != 0){
            for(i in 0..arrayList.size-1){
                val item = arrayList.get(i)
                if(item.id==last_content_id){
                    (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(i, view.getTop())
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return view
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    val position:Int=(recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val data=arrayList.get(position)
    last_content_id=data.id
    (ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel::class.java)).setHistory(data.id,data.category_id)
}
```

`(recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` allways returns **0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it before `super.onDestroy()`.

Result code should be:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    val position:Int=(recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val data=arrayList.get(position)
    last_content_id=data.id
    (ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel::class.java)).setHistory(data.id,data.category_id)
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

**EDIT**

According to the documentation

> Returns the adapter position of the first visible view. This position
>   does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last
>   layout pass.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I did it, but the result is same.

Comment: I have try also in the onStop, the result is same. For testing I tried also in onScrollStateChanged (RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()), the result is same, always returns 0.

Comment: @ABDU when you're passing the LayoutManager to the recyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

Specify adapter

```
init {
    setHasStableIds(true)
}
```

and

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I did it, but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change onDestroy(), so you call super.onDestroy() when you are done with saving state.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    val position:Int=(recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val data=arrayList.get(position)
    last_content_id=data.id 
    (ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel::class.java)) .setHistory(data.id,data.category_id)

    super.onDestroy()
}
```